# strcmp() Segmentation Fault in C

Tags: c, pointers, segmentation-fault, strcmp

When I call this function, my code always breaks in the `strcmp` and returns a `Segmentation Error` with no more information provided.

```
stop_t *getStop(char *name) {
    node_t *current = stop_list_head;
    stop_t *stop;

    while (current != NULL) {
        stop = current->stop;
        if (stop != NULL) {
            if (stop->name != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(stop->name, name) == 0) {
                    return stop;
                }
            }
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}
```

When I Inserted a `printf("%s", stop->name);` it returned the same Segmentation Fault but on the `printf`.

How can I fix this?

Minimal Reproducible Example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH_STOP 50

typedef struct {
    int routeCounter;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    char name[MAX_LENGTH_STOP + 1];
} stop_t;

typedef struct node {
    stop_t *stop;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

void printStopList();

node_t *stop_list_head = NULL;

int main() {
    stop_t *stopPtr = NULL;
    stop_t stop;
    char name[MAX_LENGTH_STOP + 1];

    /* Input Example: Praca de Espanha ; */
    fgets(name, BUFSIZ, stdin);

    stopPtr = getStop(name);
    /* Create new stop if it doesn't exist already, else print error.*/
    if (stopPtr == NULL) {
        generateStop(name);
    } else {
        printf("<Error 01>: Stop already exists.\n");
    }
}

/* Determines if the stop already exists based on the name */
stop_t *getStop(char *name) {
    node_t *current = stop_list_head;
    stop_t *stop;

    while (current != NULL) {
        stop = current->stop;
        if (stop != NULL) {
            if (stop->name != NULL) {
                if (strcmp(stop->name, name) == 0) {
                    return stop;
                }
            }
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* Generates a stop instance and adds it to the global linked list*/
void generateStop(char name[]) {
    stop_t *stop = NULL;

    stop = (stop_t *)malloc(sizeof(stop_t));

    strcpy(stop->name, name);
    stop->routeCounter = 0;
    addStopToList(stop);
    free(stop);
}

/* Adds created stops to a global linked list (stop_list_head)*/
void addStopToList(stop_t *stop) {

    node_t *new_node = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    node_t *current;

    new_node->stop = stop;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (stop_list_head == NULL) {
        stop_list_head = new_node;
    } else {
        current = stop_list_head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = new_node;
    }

    free(new_node);
}
```

Comment: 2 good candidates: `stop->name` may be a null pointer, `name` may be a null pointer.

Comment: The edit points to the problem being `stop->name`. Another problem could be that `stop->name` is missing the null terminator.

Comment: Where exactly did you insert `printf("%s", stop->name);`?

Comment: @Barmar: many `printf` implementations would not crash on a null pointer, but print `(null)` or something similar

Comment: Please post a [mre]. As you can tell, there are many problems that can result in segmentation fault.,

Comment: @chqrlie True, which suggests that the problem is the null terminator. It could also be that `stop->name` is not initialized at all, so it's an invalid pointer.

Comment: @Barmar: I suspect the OP inserted the `printf` before the `if`

Comment: `if(stop != NULL)` should be before `stop = current->stop;`

Comment: With all these changes, I'm leaning strongly to a missing null terminator in `stop->name`.

Comment: Extra context: `stop_list_head` is initially declared as a NULL pointer to a node_t structure.

Comment: @chqrlie they can also be dangling or wild

Comment: And what happens to `stop_list_head` after that? This is why we need a [mre] in the question. You haven't shown us your entire program -- and since you don't know where the problem is, you don't know what information you can safely leave out.

Comment: This would also be a good time to learn to use a debugger. When the program stops with the segmentation fault you can examine the pointer to see what it contains. https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Comment: Using `stop.name` and `stop->name` shows that the OP code is not (cannot) be correct... What's the point?

Comment: Looks like you need to sit down with pencil and paper (and your rubber duck) to draw what happens with the data you enter. Hint: If the instances of `struct` are `free()`'d at then end of a function in which they are allocated, then they do not exist anymore. Think about the data and structures you want to preserve when a function ends...

Comment: Great -- but you need to compile with warnings enabled. You declare `printStopList()` but never define or call it. You call several functions with no visible declaration. And using `BUFSIZ` in your call to `fgets` makes no sense; you want the size of the array you're reading into.

Comment: Do not free structures until you need to reference them.

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple problems:

- you free the newly allocated structures in the functions supposed to allocate them.  This causes undefined behavior when they are later read, eg: when `strcmp` accesses `stop->name`
- you read `name` with `fgets` passing an invalid size `BUFSIZ` much larger than `MAX_LENGTH_STOP + 1`.  This may cause a buffer overflow
- you do not test the return value of `fgets()`, causing invalid behavior if redirected from an empty file.
- `fgets()` leaves the trailing newline at the end of the `name` array: it will be stored into the stop list.
- `strcpy(stop->name, name);` may cause a buffer overflow if the `name` argument is longer than the `name` field in the `stop_t` structure.
- the minimal example does not actually cause a segmentation fault where you report it because the stop list is empty.

Here is a modified version:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define MAX_LENGTH_STOP 50

typedef struct stop {
    int routeCounter;
    double latitude;
    double longitude;
    char name[MAX_LENGTH_STOP + 1];
} stop_t;

typedef struct node {
    stop_t *stop;
    struct node *next;
} node_t;

node_t *stop_list_head;

/* Determines if the stop already exists based on the name */
stop_t *getStop(const char *name) {
    node_t *current = stop_list_head;

    while (current != NULL) {
        stop_t *stop = current->stop;
        if (stop != NULL && strcmp(stop->name, name) == 0) {
            return stop;
        }
        current = current->next;
    }
    return NULL;
}

/* Adds created stops to a global linked list (stop_list_head)*/
void addStopToList(stop_t *stop) {
    node_t *new_node = (node_t *)malloc(sizeof(node_t));
    if (new_node == NULL) {
        perror("cannot allocate node_t");
        exit(1);
    }

    new_node->stop = stop;
    new_node->next = NULL;

    if (stop_list_head == NULL) {
        stop_list_head = new_node;
    } else {
        node_t *current = stop_list_head;
        while (current->next != NULL) {
            current = current->next;
        }
        current->next = new_node;
    }
}

/* Generates a stop instance and adds it to the global linked list*/
void generateStop(const char *name) {
    stop_t *stop = (stop_t *)calloc(sizeof(stop_t), 1);
    if (stop == NULL) {
        perror("cannot allocate stop_t");
        exit(1);
    }
    strncat(stop->name, name, sizeof(stop->name) - 1);
    addStopToList(stop);
}

int main(void) {
    for (;;) {
        char name[MAX_LENGTH_STOP + 2];

        /* Input Example: Praça de Espanha ; */
        if (!fgets(name, sizeof name, stdin))
            return 1;
        /* strip the trailing newline if present */
        name[strcspn(name, "\n")] = '\0';
        /* stop on an empty line */
        if (*name == '\0')
            break;
        /* Create new stop if it doesn't exist already, else print error.*/
        if (getStop(name)) {
            printf("<Error 01>: Stop already exists: %s\n", name);
        } else {
            generateStop(name);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```